# ng2-datepicker initialDate is appending to every month date automatically

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I'm using ng2-datepicker. I'm using options like below and HTML written like follow.

```
 <ng2-datepicker  [options]="options" [(ngModel)]="Enddate" name="EndDate"></ng2-datepicker>

 this.options = {
            initialDate: new Date(),
            format: "DD-MMM-YYYY",
            firstWeekdaySunday: true,

        };
```

In date picker, the initial day value is highlighting in every month.How to remove that in ng2-datepicker.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried mydatepicker?

Comment: https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker

Comment: No I haven't used

Comment: You should use this, It has better view and lots of configuration.

Comment: Thanks, let's search for a solution. I will have a look later. because ng2-date picker everything is integrated into my project